# Can I benchmark Apache ignite with YCSB?

Tags: ignite

I am looking for a tool to benchmark Ignite, an in-memory data grid.
I actually saw the Ignite Benchmark from YCSB.
Can I use the YCSB Benchmark Tool for In-memory Data Grid Ignite?

Answer (score 1):

I had experience of benchmarking Ignite, using [Yardstick](https://github.com/gridgain/yardstick) framework. You can find existing benchmarks in the Ignite repository: https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/modules/yardstick

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to benchmark any use case Ignite is being used for with YCSB - let it be Ignite as In-Memory Data Grid or Ignite as a Distributed Database.

[This](https://dzone.com/articles/apachereg-ignite-and-apachereg-cassandra-benchmark) Ignite vs. Cassandra benchmark is based on YCSB and here is a [repository](https://github.com/spuchnin/YCSB_IG) with the sources.